# How can I create custom error page for 500 Internal server error in next.js app router?

Tags: error-handling, next.js13, custom-error-handling, app-router

In the previous versions of next.js and current version with page router, I know that there is an ability to handle it buy only creating a 500.js/jsx/tsx file and export default a react component. but I didn't find anything about it in app router.

Comment: I have Next js page router project that contains 400,404,500 files. after converting It into app router i git this error at build time
```
 Build error occurred
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
/upgrade-ledger/.next/server/pages/500.html'] {
```

Answer (score 3):

As of **NextJS v14**, with App router,

This is not possible. (Some pertinent discussions can be found on [github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/52378))

As a workaround,

You could add a specific route, `/error` (/app/error/page.tsx) and  then redirect to this path when a server error happens.

For example, on your server component (`api/route.js`)

```js
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

try {
   // something that throws an error
   throw new Error("Internal server error");
}
catch (e) {
   // your should probably log the error as well 
   redirect('/error?status=500&message=servererror');
}
```

Then in your `/app/error/page.tsx`

```js
const ErrorPage = ({ searchParams }: { searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined } }) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Error {searchParams.status}</h1>
      <p>{searchParams.message}</p>
    </main>
  );
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

To redirect all 5xx errors to your error page, you could write a wrapper like

```js
/* /app/helpers/errorHandler.js */

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

function withErrorHandler(fn) {
  return async function (request, ...args) {
    try {
      return await fn(request, ...args);
    } catch (error) {
      // Log the error to a logging system
      
      // Respond with a generic 500 Internal Server Error
      redirect('/error?status=500&message=servererror');
    }
  };
}

export default withErrorHandler;


/**** Then use this in your routes (route.js) ****/

import "...";

export const GET = withErrorHandler(async (request) => {
  await runFunctionHelloWorld();
  // Return a successful response if no errors occurred
  return NextResponse.json({ success: true }, { status: 200 });
});
```

[Reference for wrapper](https://medium.com/@matijazib/global-error-handling-in-the-backend-with-next-js-13-api-d60ccbec27dd)

Comment: You cant redirect from the API route. At least I certainly cannot.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you have to create an error.tsx file

for example

dashboard
-page.tsx
-error.tsx

page.tsx
error.tsx