How do i change status code of a Next js page
I want to set the status code 503 for some of pages in my Next app. Is it possible?
right now every page even those that are undefined gets status code 200. how can i manipulate it?
By the way, by status code i mean the status of the page not the api call response
Next 13.5
  const StatePage = async ({ params, error }) => {
  const state = capitalizeFirstLetter(params.state);
  const states = [
    "Federal",
    "Ontario",
    "Quebec",
    "Nova-Scotia",
    "Saskatchewan",
    "Newfoundland-and-Labrador",
    "New-Brunswick",
    "Manitoba",
    "Prince-Edward-Island",
    "Yukon",
    "Northwest-Territories",
    "British-Columbia",
    "Alberta",
  ];

  if (error) {
    return <NotFound error={error} />;
  } else if (states.includes(state)) {
    // redirect(`https://${baseUrl}/landing/${params.state}`);
    throw new Error(503)
  } else notFound()
};

export default StatePage;

I actually couldn't find a way to make it happen.
Edit: I ended up using nextjs middleware. I add the middleware in the root of my project and used nextjs url matcher to show 503 error of specific route.
The only downside was I cant use my 503 custom error page in here.
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";

export function middleware(request) {
 const componentString = renderToString(someHtml)

      return new NextResponse(componentString, {
    status: 503,
    headers: { "content-type": " text/html; charset=utf-8" },
  });
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/fa/programs/:country/:path/",
};


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please refer to the docs:
https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/seo/crawling-and-indexing/status-codes
You can set any response code that you wish 
If I didn’t understand you correctly, please explain further what you are looking for.

if im right in the docs it only explains how to create a 50* error page, it doesnt explain how to set http status code.

To get that you will need the ‘getServerSideProps’ to return an error (if you are using the pages router)

Thank you, but I'm using App router

In that case, please see this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77051205/how-can-i-create-custom-error-page-for-500-internal-server-error-in-next-js-app

Happy to help! Can you please approve my answer? @neginshafaei
